# Build scipy objective function dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, scipy

What I am trying to accomplish:
Trying to use the scipy optimize minimize feature and build the lambda objective function dynamically.

So I want 1 function to build and return a lambda and I want it to take in arguments.  So for example I want to build:

```
def build_lambdas([params]):
   for param in params:
     lambda.var = param.var
     lambda.coeff = param.coeff
```

y = 4 + 3y
or 
y = 2x + 5y + 4z 
or 
y = 5x + 3z + 2r + 0.5p

depending on whatever I pass in.

What's the best way to accomplish this?  I've seen a number of examples for trying to dynamically update the values of x within a lambda, but what I'm after is doing this with the variable and the coefficient to be optimized.

So I'm looking for ideas, tips, examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me why you want to pass this as arguments, instead of just building the lambda directly. You can of course just pass a lambda as argument as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
def build_lambda(*coefficients):
   return lambda *vars: np.dot(coefficients, vars)

l = build_lambda(2,3)
print(l(3,4))  # 18
```

It is then only constrained to linear equations, but you could extend the concept to polynomials.

Comment: thanks, this is more or less what i'm after.  Yeah, I'll extend to polynomials for more complex functions.